# cordova/phonegap push notifications unregister() returns success even with internet off

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications

I'm using the Phonegap push plugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) and have the following function (and success and error calbacks) which is called when I turn off notifications via a toggle

```
function pushNotificationOFF() {
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.unregister(pushNotificationOffSuccess,
        pushNotificationOffError);
}

function pushNotificationOffSuccess() {
    alert("Noticications are OFF");
}

function pushNotificationOffError() {
    alert("Error turning noticications off");
}
```

On both iOS7 and Android 4.x, with the internet OFF (cell and wifi) the success function is being called, I would have expected that the error callback would fire instead?

What am I missing here and how would one ensure that you do not send notifications to someone that has switched them off while the device is offline?

**Edit 4 Feb with results of testing**

```
ANDROID Tablet
14:12:23 wifi off
14:14:23 turned notifications off
14:18:59 wifi on
14:36:08 sent push, received


IOS tablet
15.25 wifi off
15.35 turned notifications off
15.42 wifi on
16:00 sent push, NOT received




All devices
=================================

16.30 all have wi fi on, notifications on,  and receive push
16.34 turned off wifi on all
16.45 turned off notifications on all
16.55 turned ON wifi on all
17.40 sent push
17.47 not received on any device, sending another push
17.56 not received on any device


All devices 3rd feb
=================================
11.50 all have wi fi on, notifications on,  and receive push
11.55 turned OFF wifi on all
12.05 turned off notifications on all and CLOSED APP
12.45 turned ON wifi on all
13.00 sent push - received by 3 x android - but not by ios and appears in ios feedback

---------------------------------

13.40 all have wi fi on, notifications on,  and receive push
13.41 unplugged wifi
13.46 turned off notifications on all and CLOSED APP
14.07 turned on wifi
15.00 sent push - received by 2 x android - but not by ios and appears in ios feedback

---------------------------------


15.59 all have wi fi on, notifications on,  and receive push
16.00 unplugged wifi
16.02 turned off notifications on all and backgrounded app
16.43 turned on wifi
17.41 sent push - no push received on any device and one android NotRegistered returned

SUMMARY OF TODAY

seems IOS does turn off notifications (when back online again) if toggle was changed while offline
android seems to do it also, provided 
a) there is time (ie 30 min between going online again, and sending push)
b) you background app instead of closing it, after changing the toggle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described on [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg-why) the unregistration doesn't happen instantly. Instead it may take up 5 minutes for unregistration to propagate. What happens during this 5 minutes is

> During this time messages may be rejected due to the state of being unregistered, and after all this, messages may still go to the wrong user.

So your will to unregister has been successfully received and the process has been started and thus is the success callback called.

Here is the code for unregister call from the *PushPlugin.java* which is responsible for responding to JS

```
GCMRegistrar.unregister(getApplicationContext());
Log.v(TAG, "UNREGISTER");
result = true;
callbackContext.success();
```

As you can see, the only case where it can fail practically is on *GCMRegistrar.unregister* which doesn't even wait for the GCM server to respond "okay, unregistered" thus leading to always returning success.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I understand correctly, I will always get a success response even if the device is offline? So what is a user hits the control toggle to stop notifications while offline, how can I unregister that user/device?

Comment: @KevInSol: Yes, it looks like that at least for Android (I'm not too keen on reading Objective C..). I suppose that the device sends the _unregistration_ request when it gets it's connection back and the GCM doesn't poll the device all the time to send the notification, so the chances are that the unregistration is done before the waiting notification gets sent. But I suppose it can't be prevented totally.

Comment: Thanks. I hope to get the sending part (ie connect to the GCM/APNS api) done tomorrow/Monday so can test if that is how it goes. I'll report my findings here!

Comment: I updated my question with results of testing the unregistration while offline